# Make - Multiple definitions errors when compiling C++ project

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, compiler-errors, extern

I have a problem and yes ***I acknowledge this kind of question has been asked before***, but none of them were really helping me, as the context and kind of errors given were not exactly the same.

I have a project I'm trying to compile with a makefile. The compilation process is the following :

```
game_f.exe : objects/game_f.o objects/game_f_main.o archives/io.a
    @g++ $^ $(ALL_OTHER_NEEDED_LIBS) -o $@ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -g
```

Now those lines are creating 'multiple definitions' errors. Such as those :

```
io.cpp:(.text+0x1FDA) : multiple definitions of <some function or variable name> :
archives/io.a(io.o):io.cpp:(.text+0x1FDA) : defined for the first time here
```

Now this is coming from a header file where I create a namespace. The namespace is created as such :

*io.h* :

```
namespace io {
    extern int TermWidth;
    [some other variables, declared with "extern <some type> name;"]
    extern void getTermWidth();
    [some other functions, declared with "extern <some type> name(args)"
}
```

*io.cpp* :

```
namespace io {
    TermWidth = 0;
    [other variables definitions]
    void getTermWidth() { ... }
}
```

The compiler seems to ignore the `extern` word when compiling from the makefile. But what is weird is ***if I type the entire g++ line, without going through the makefile***, the compilation works.

This compiles fine on my macOS machine when going through the makefile, by the way, which is even weirder.

Does g++ have a special option for `extern` definitions ? Is this a known problem of `g++` and `make` ? How could I avoid this error ?

EDIT : Yes, the .h files have include guards.

Comment: Do you header files have include guards?  You're not including a cpp file anywhere are you?

Comment: Yes , they include headers guards (I even added `#pragma once` for more safety, don't know if that does anything). I'm not including a .cpp file anywhere (always including .h files).

Comment: You can try removing io.o from io.a and see if the functions are defined in some other files.

Comment: I'm so dumb. One of the included libs in `$(ALL_OTHER_NEEDED_LIBS)` was io.o and as such, all definitions were doubled. Thanks for the help !